# how to get identifier of current segue

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a bug in a rendering of a view but only when the user hits the back button in a UINavigationController. I am thinking about just supressing the offending code via something like this:

```
if(currentSuge.identifier isEqualToString:@'pushItemSegue'){
   doCode // only in this situation
}
```

How would I get the name of the identifier of the current segue?

Comment: Are you asking how you'd get `currentSegue`?

Comment: yes, sorry - how to get currentSegue in the above sample code. tried googling UIStoryboard - not sure if this is available globally but hoping :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You cannot simply get the "current Segue" at any point in the app. Because Segues Exist **only** at specific points in time during your Apps Life cycle. That being when your app is preparing for the transition from one view controller to another and also during the actual visual transition.

The best you can do is override `-prepareForSegue:` and store the UIStoryboardSegue somewhere in your ViewController as a property.

more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    //Here you have name of your segue
    NSLog(@"Segue name is %@", [segue identifier]);

    //Use this to performe some action
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushItemSegue"])
    {
        //your code
    }

    //Add this for next seque
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"secondSegue"])
    {
        //someting else
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the correct answer to the question. You should re-read it.